# Getting class name in SWIFT equivalent to Objective C [self class]?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using the following syntax to debug my Objective C code, getting the class name. What is the equivalent in SWIFT?

```
NSlog (@"Classe = %@",[self class]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print("Class = \(type(of: self))"` in Swift.

Comment: pretty sure you know it's a duplicate